# How do eliminate/remove a gem that is throwing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, torquebox

When I run the rails console command, I'm getting the following error messages:

```
Invalid gemspec in [/Users/MI1/torquebox-2.0.0.beta1/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/specifications/ZenTest-4.9.0.gemspec]: Illformed requirement ["< 2.1, >= 1.8"]
```

When I ran gem uninstall zentest, the system said zentest was not installed.

Does anyone know how can remove this gem and annoying error message.

Comment: Do you have different Ruby versions? Maybe you server is running in version 1.8 and anything else in version 1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to make sure you don't have multiple versions of the gem

```
gem cleanup
```

then

```
sudo gem uninstall zentest
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried gem cleanup followed by sudo gem uninstall zentest but unfortunately that did not fix my problem.

Ultimately, I simply deleted the file and the error message was eliminated.

Thanks for the input.